# Maven central only contains pom. How to add jar?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to mavenize a project, which is using IBM MQ.
In our Nexus-server, only the pom exists:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.07</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This is, as I understand, MQ is proprietary software.
I do have the jar-files for MQ.
How do I add these to the project, and also keep the dependencies that is specified by the pom.

Can I upload the jars to our Nexus, so the it also contains the jar (With the pom),
or can I add both a pom dependency and some cand of system or import, with the jar in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to upload the jar into your corporate repository. This way, any developer will be able to use this dependency without any issues. You just need to perform [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) with the following 2 options:

- same groupId, artifactId, version
- `-DgeneratePom=false`